# Coupon creating using child product of a Configurable products

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I want to create a coupon using variance of a configurable product.Suppose,i have configurable product(Cp-01),it have three child simple products. Color of product is red,green,blue consequentially. I have create a coupon it will apply when size red and sku is Cp-01 .Please help me

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it but if you add as condition that both the configurable product SKU and the simple product red SKU are present in cart it should work.

Make sure to set the attribute "SKU" to be usable for promotional rules and then apply the conditions along the lines of the following

[image]

Comment: Sander ,it was partially work..... we need to remove configurable product sku

Comment: ah ok :) well as I said, I didn't test. I'm glad it works when omitting configurable SKU